# Solve $2\cos x + 1 = 0$ for x, where $\pi \le x \le \frac{3\pi}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

> Solve $2\cos x + 1$ for x, where $\pi \le x \le \frac{3\pi}{2}$
>
> A) $5\frac{\pi}6$
>
> B) $7\frac{\pi}6$
>
> C) $5\frac{\pi}4$
>
> D) $4\frac{\pi}3$

$2\cos x + 1 = 0$

$2\cos^2 x -1 + 1 = 0$

$2\cos^2 x = 0$

Should I be using the double angle formula for this?  If so, how do I simplify $\cos^2$

Comment: One could just substitute each answer into the formula and check if the answer is 0 (if one could bring a calculator).

Comment: I assume you mean $2\cos x + 1 = 0$?

Comment: no calculator for this paper

Comment: Your second line does not follow from the first, and I think the problem doesn't call for anything even that complicated.  You are just being asked to know values for trigonometric functions at "fundamental angles" (multiples of $ \ \frac{\pi}{4} \ $ and $ \ \frac{\pi}{6} \ ) \ $ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2cos(x)=4cos^2(x/2)-2$ so equation becomes $4cos^2(x/2)-1=0$ thus $cos(x/2)=|0.5|$ now get the desired angle

Comment: how does $4\cos^2(\frac{x}{2})-1 = 0$ become $\cos(\frac{x}{2})=0.5$

Comment: Taking square root. Nothing much just cut some simple steps

Comment: if possible, could you add the steps.  I think I'm missing how you got there

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos x=-\dfrac12=-\cos\dfrac\pi3=\cos\left(\pi-\dfrac\pi3\right)$$  as $\cos(\pi\pm u)=-\cos u$

$$\implies x=2m\pi\pm\dfrac{2\pi}3$$

Find suitable value of integer $m$ so that $$\pi\le x\le\dfrac{3\pi}2$$

Comment: Not just a suitable value of $ \ m \ $ , but the appropriate sign on the term $ \  \pm \frac{2 \pi}{3} \ $ .